# Sort and remove duplicate items from array - REST API SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have successfully collated the results from multiple lists from SharePoint Online in a grid using REST API.

However, the collated resultset array is not in order and has duplicate elements. I need to order the grid, so that it is sorted based on created date desc and only has unique items.

I used the below code and RemoveDuplicatesItems[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LqEr.png) function. The code executes fine and removes duplicates, but the grid shows all columns as undefined once i remove duplicates. If i don't execute the duplicate function , grid displays data, but with duplicates.

Any technical advice would be much helpful to me. Looking forward to hear from you. Thanks all.

```html
<script src="https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ListDataCollection = {
    Lists:[{
        Url:"https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sites1/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,Description,Action_x0020_By_x003a_,RequestFrom_x003a_,Created&$filter=Category eq 'Key Events and Decision'",
        Completed:false
    },{
        Url:"https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sites2/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,Description,Action_x0020_By_x003a_,RequestFrom_x003a_,Created&$filter=Category eq 'Key Events and Decision'",
        Completed:false
    },{
        Url:"https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sites3/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,Description,Action_x0020_By_x003a_,RequestFrom_x003a_,Created&$filter=Category eq 'Key Events and Decision'",
        Completed:false
    }]
};
var tableContent = '<table id="tableEmployee" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><b>No</b></td>' + 

'<td><b>Description</b></td>' + '<td><b>Action By</b></td>' + '<td><b>Request From</b></td>' + '<td><b>Created</b></td>'+ 

'</tr></thead><tbody>';

function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
       if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
       }
    });
    return result;
}
function RemoveDuplicateItems(items, propertyName) {
    var result = [];
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result) == -1) {
                result.push(item[propertyName]);
            }
        });
    return result;
}
function ifAllCompleted() {
    for (var i=0;i<ListDataCollection.Lists.length;i++) {
     
        if (!ListDataCollection.Lists[i].Completed) {
            return false;
        }   
    }
 console.log('Completed');   
    var arrayOfAllData = ListDataCollection.Lists[0].Data.d.results;
    arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[1].Data.d.results);
    arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[2].Data.d.results);
 console.log('Total elements : ' + arrayOfAllData.length);
 arrayOfAllData=RemoveDuplicateItems(arrayOfAllData,'Description')
 for( var i=0; i<arrayOfAllData.length;i++)
 {
     tableContent += '<tr>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Title+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Description+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].RequestFrom_x003a_+ '</td>';
     tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Created+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '</tr>';
 }
 $('#employeeGrid').append(tableContent);
 
 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var x=0;x<ListDataCollection.Lists.length;x++) {
        $.ajax({
            url:ListDataCollection.Lists[x].Url,
            indexValue:x,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Data = data;
                ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Completed = true;
                ifAllCompleted();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });     
    }
});
</script>
 <div id="CustomerPanel">
        <table id="tableEmployee" border="1 px" style="width: 100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="employeeGrid" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're push a `result.push(item[propertyName])` instead of item.

Sample script:

```
<script>
    var ListDataCollection = {
        Lists: [{
            Url: "url1",
            Completed: false
        }, {
                Url: "url2",
            Completed: false
        }, {
                Url: "url3",
            Completed: false
        }]
    };
    var tableContent = '<table id="tableEmployee" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><b>No</b></td>' +

        '<td><b>Description</b></td>' + '<td><b>Action By</b></td>' + '<td><b>Request From</b></td>' + '<td><b>Created</b></td>' +

        '</tr></thead><tbody>';

    function groupBy(items, propertyName) {
        var result = [];
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result) == -1) {
                result.push(item[propertyName]);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
    function checkDuplicateInObject(propertyName,value, inputArray) {
        var seenDuplicate = false;            
        inputArray.map(function (item) {
            var itemPropertyName = item[propertyName];
            if (itemPropertyName == value) {                    
                seenDuplicate = true;
                return seenDuplicate;
            }
        });

        return seenDuplicate;
    }
    function RemoveDuplicateItems(items, propertyName) {
        var result = [];
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if (!checkDuplicateInObject(propertyName, item[propertyName], result)) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
    function ifAllCompleted() {
        for (var i = 0; i < ListDataCollection.Lists.length; i++) {

            if (!ListDataCollection.Lists[i].Completed) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        console.log('Completed');
        var arrayOfAllData = ListDataCollection.Lists[0].Data.d.results;
        arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[1].Data.d.results);
        arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[2].Data.d.results);
        console.log('Total elements : ' + arrayOfAllData.length);
        arrayOfAllData = RemoveDuplicateItems(arrayOfAllData, 'Description')
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfAllData.length; i++) {
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Title + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Description + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_ + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].RequestFrom_x003a_ + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Created + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        }
        $('#employeeGrid').append(tableContent);


    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var x = 0; x < ListDataCollection.Lists.length; x++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: ListDataCollection.Lists[x].Url,
                indexValue: x,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Data = data;
                    ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Completed = true;
                    ifAllCompleted();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<div id="CustomerPanel">
    <table id="tableEmployee" border="1 px" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="employeeGrid" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lee_MSFT for helping me to correct my mistakes. It worked fine now. I am trying to sort the retrieved resultset based on "Created" field descending. I used JQuery sort function to sort out the array based on date, but couldn't succeed. Any inputs on date sorting would be helpful a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: I used the lodash _SortBy function to sort the dates based on Created.            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js></script> 
arrayOfAllData=  _.SortBy(arrayOfAllData,['Created'],['desc']);       However, the code doesnt return anything. Not sure what went wrong